# How to erase 'nan' values that are in a certain column using pandas?

Tags: python

I have a column that has bunch of rows with a mixture of 'nan'.
I only want to delete 'nan', not the entire row that includes 'nan'.
Some cells in that column have multiple nans like: nan,nan,nan,nan
and some cells has the name that I need with nan attached like: Jefferson,nan,nan,nan

How can I just erase nan?

Comment: NaN is the absence of data. You cannot have both a representation of the fact that there is no data in a particular cell and also somehow delete that representation.

Comment: The question is not well explained. I thin what you need is type casting. After that you would be able to skip nan rows. But you are not explaining clearly all type if nans you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I'm using regular expressions to match `'nan'` only or `'nan,<something>'` and I'm replacing that by an empty string `''`.

I decided to use regex because by your question I think you can't use a literal string since you don't know exactly is within the cell (can be any number of `'nan's`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'names': ['Jefferson', 'nan', 'Olivia', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan,nan,nan', 'Rebekah'],
        'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df['names'] = df['names'].replace({r'^nan$': '', r'^nan,.*': ''}, regex=True)
df
```

If we are not talking about the string `'nan'` then the `df.fillna('')` should do.

Comment: This almost worked but it is not deleting nan in cells with names like "Jefferson[asddf],nan,nan,nan"

Comment: ok that's another use case. Try `df['names'] = df['names'].replace({r'^nan$': '', r'nan,.*': '', r',': '',}, regex=True)` . Maybe this works but in order to find a better solution it's important to know what are all the scenarios possible

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace nan with some value, like 0 or ""?
[pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From : [geekforgeek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replace-nan-values-with-zeros-in-pandas-dataframe/)

Methods to replace NaN values with zeros in Pandas DataFrame:

```
fillna()
The fillna() function is used to fill NA/NaN values using the specified method.
replace()
The dataframe.replace() function in Pandas can be defined as a simple method used to replace a string, regex, list, dictionary etc. in a DataFrame.
```

Steps to replace NaN values:

```
For one column using pandas:

df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].fillna(0)

For one column using numpy:

df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].replace(np.nan, 0)

For the whole DataFrame using pandas:

df.fillna(0)

For the whole DataFrame using numpy:

df.replace(np.nan, 0)
```

MY ADVICE : as you use strings, replace NaN by a space " " and when processing your dataframe skip the value when == " "